# Imported Cloudwatch LogsInsights query to Grafana display only 1 record

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Hi I have been trying to import dashboard from cloudwatch to Grafana. Where i have a visual made using LogInsight query.

Sample query that i an using is

```
fields @timestamp, @recordCount, @logStream
| sort @timestamp desc
| parse @message /((?<=deduplication:\s)(?<@recordCount>\d+))/
| filter @message like /Record count after deduplication/
| stats max(@recordCount) as recordCount by @logStream
| limit 20
```

I am able to fetched required logs in cloud watch.
[image: Fetched logs inside cloudwatch]

but when i import the same query in Grafana i get only a single record. The stats in query inspector do show "total number rows : 21" but data returned has only 1

[image: Grafan Stats inside the query inspector for same query]
[image: Grafan Fetched records]

I am facing same issue on all LogInsight quires